# How to add a Custom Strip with a Custom Chunk and Button in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

As per subject - I want to create a custom button in a new Strip; the instructions that used to work for Sitecore 7.5 (adding a Strip Item under /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Strips, etc.) don't seem to work anymore in 8.1.

Can anyone link detailed documentation to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, right-click on the toolbar and see if you have the new menu listed as shown in the screenshot below. If not please see the following steps:

1. Navigate to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks`and create a new Chunk. The template is at `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Chunk`
2. Create your button in the newly created Chunk which is based on the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Large Button`
3. Navigate to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Strips` and create your new Strip from the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Strip`
4. Then, add a reference for your Chunk using the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Reference` and in the droptree, select your created Chunk
5. Navigate to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Ribbons/Default` and create a reference using the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Reference` and select your strip from the droptree.
6. Refresh the page and see if it is present. If not, right click on the toolbar and see if you have your new navigation list as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This works, but now inside my new Ribbon I don't see the button I created - instead I see "Save" and "Customize". Any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: Can you please provide more details and screenshots about the different path used and so on

Comment: Everything was done properly, but there were _other_ incomplete Chunks and Ribbons; after removing them, my new Strip stopped showing up altogether. So I started over again with a dummy strip, and this time it works. So now I will delete everything and restart from scratch, and hopefully it will work.

This entire process is so buggy and convoluted, it's amazing how Sitecore developers are willing to put up with it.

Comment: Yeah, but once you are used to it, it will be much faster to create new Strips and so on. Can you please marked the answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: I'm not done yet - I will mark it once it proves to be accurate.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Out of curiosity, where else can this knowledge be found? Is there some obscure documentation pdf hidden somewhere at Sitecore's HQ?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe in the release notes. I also did not find any documentation about this